# How to log all Doctrine queries to file?

Tags: doctrine

I'm using Doctrine and want to log all generated SQL queries.

I know that I could use `$q->getSqlQuery()` but I don't want to do that manually each time.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: If you run in development mode, this is normally enabled automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn logging on all queries shoudl be logged to your application log in the `log` directory. To do this set `logging_enabled` to true in your `settings.yml`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Doctrine Profiler](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/component-overview:profiler) and the source of [ZF_Debug & Doctrine](http://www.danceric.net/2009/06/06/zfdebug-and-doctrine-orm/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using symfony...

In some **config.yaml** file (i.e. config/packages/monolog.yaml) you can add something like:

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        doctrine:
            action_level: debug
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log'
            channels: doctrine
```

and in **doctrine.yaml** config, just make sure you have the logging enabled.

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        logging: true
```

This will log every query in  `<logs_dir>/<env>_doctrine.log`.

Source: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/61q2/storing-doctrine-queries-in-a-file-log-with-symfony