# How to display the SQL query that causes a PDOException in Doctrine

Tags: php, exception, phpunit, doctrine-orm

I am playing with Doctrine 2 and PHPUnit and of course, something goes wrong sometimes. That's what unittesting is all about. But when I get a PDOException for one reason or the other, I don't get to see the query that is causing it. Example:

```
$ phpunit --group database
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 14.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) My\Tests\Entity\MyMappingTest::testLoad
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't11.id' in 'on clause'

/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:613
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:569
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:624
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1979
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php:139
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php:44
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:99
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:580
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:130
/usr/local/svn/php5/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:350


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

That's all fine and dandy, but how do I tell Doctrine or PHPUnit to give me the SQL query that is causing this exception so that I have any hope of debugging it? Right now, this exception is kind of useless. I tried var_dumping the exception object but that just recurses forever. Surely I should be able to tell Doctrine to give me more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [enable native Doctrine SQL logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800226/how-to-log-all-doctrine-queries-to-file), or with a bit more effort you could implement `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger` to store the last query and override `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::onNotSuccessfulTest()` to add it a new exception in the case of a `PDOException`. Unfortunately, you'll lose the original stack trace, but PHP doesn't allow changing an exception's message once it's created. :(

Use `setSQLLogger()` on the config object to use your logger. Do this in PHPUnit `bootstrap.php` and make it available to your test case base class.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good. I'll give this a try when I am back at work tomorrow.